# hamcrest: comparing two collections ob custom class logically using hamcrest

Tags: java, hamcrest

I've two `Collection<Dumb>` I need to compare using hamcrest:

```
public class Dumb {
    private String id;

    //setters & getters
}
```

Shortly and straightforwardly,

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Collection<Dumb> actual = new ArrayList<Dumb>();
    Dumb actualDumbOne = new Dumb();
    actualDumbOne.setId("1");
    Dumb actualDumbTwo = new Dumb();
    actualDumbTwo.setId("2");
    actual.add(actualDumbOne);
    actual.add(actualDumbTwo);

    Collection<Dumb> expected = new ArrayList<Dumb>();
    Dumb expectedDumbOne = new Dumb();
    expectedDumbOne.setId("1");
    Dumb expectedDumbTwo = new Dumb();
    expectedDumbTwo.setId("2");
    expected.add(expectedDumbOne);
    expected.add(expectedDumbTwo);

    assertThat(expected, containsInAnyOrder(actual));
}
```

It fails due to:

```
Expected: iterable over [<[Dumb@56114349, Dumb@46c28400]>] in any order
     but: Not matched: <Dumb@2d6abfc7>
```

**Important**: I can't change `Dumb` code, it's a third-party class.
**Important**: I need to compare that `Dumb.id is equals to Dumb.id`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to compare the Dumb.id members, you can extract the ids into a list and compare the resulting id-list.

```
    List<String> actualIds = actual.stream().map(Dumb::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> expectedIds = expected.stream().map(Dumb::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertThat(expectedIds, containsInAnyOrder(actualIds.toArray()));
```

Comment: But what about if you need to compare two fields? `id` and `name`? How would you solve that?

Comment: You can create a wrapper for the object. The wrapper can than implement equals and hash and delegate all other calls to its wrapped object.